# How to handle FirebaseInstanceIdService with RxJava

Tags: android, firebase, rx-java, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hello im new to Rxjava and have been in trouble with FirebaseInstanceIdService using Rxjava. The problem is that this never act sending action although the onTokenReflesh has been called.
Can anyone solve this problem?
sendRegistrationToServer is also called and i got the refreshed token but either of onCompleted,onError or onNext has never called!!!

PS: for some reasons, sometimes onCompleted is called before the service dies. so I figured the service dies at ramdom regardless of the completion of the observable. but then how should I handle this? I need this observable to finish the task. 
To be precise, when the first activity instantiated I want it to send the token that generated by FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(). However, it returns null at that time so I fail to send it to the server. Then a few seconds later the service's onTokenReflesh is called so I want to send the tokenId this time.

### my codes are below

```
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    super.onTokenRefresh();
    CLog.d("onTokenRefresh");
    // Get updated device token
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (null != mSubscription){
        mSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token){
CLog.d("token: " + token);
    Observable<ApiResult> observable =    ApiExecutor.makeClient(getApplicationContext())
            .create(UUIDApi.class)
            .createOrUpdateApplicationInfo(
                    uuid, token);
    mSubscription =
            ApiExecutor.extractAsyncObservable(observable, null)
            .subscribe(new Observer<ApiResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    CLog.d("onCompleted");
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    CLog.d("onError" + e.getMessage());
                }
                @Override
                public void onNext(ApiResult apiResult) {
                    CLog.d("onNext");
                    AppSettings.saveUUID(getApplicationContext(), uuid);
                }
            });
}

private Observable<ApiResult> extractAsyncObservable(Observable<ApiResult> observable){
    return observable
            .retry(3)
            // when subscribed
            .doOnSubscribe(() -> {
            })
            // when unSubscribed
            .doOnUnsubscribe(() -> {
            })
            // called before onNext
            .doOnNext(apiResult -> {
                if (!apiResult.isSuccess()){
                    CLog.d("result_code: " + String.valueOf(apiResult.getResultCode()));
                    // TODO determine depending on a errorMsg
                    throw new RuntimeException(determineErrorMessage(apiResult.getResultCode()));
                }
            })
            // called before onError
            .doOnError(throwable -> {
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            ;
}
```

Comment: Can you add a log in `onDestroy`. I suspect the service terminates before the observable completes. And your subscriber unsubscribes in `onDestroy` so it doesn't get notified.

Comment: @Frank`07-26 20:34:49.960 32664-1057: onTokenRefresh`
`07-26 20:34:49.960 32664-1057: UUID: df056620-90c7-4a13-b77b-6b3913de0f2c`
07-26 20:34:49.960 32664-1057: token: fJ_ftyvE8oU:APA91bGNwT3AuctheShu666DqEhDWznCcrNdXaWz-lsCUgqJiOhza_YBpuGCsdSgexpfkp9xAD_V9LZQO1QOi25FOd6UoCzBYd3ox7oWznZWzUDwQh7O5C977t463CQDtG9qof-Jblr1
07-26 20:34:50.196 32664-32664: onNext
07-26 20:34:50.196 32664-32664: onCompleted
07-26 20:34:50.380 32664-32664: onDestroy
07-26 20:34:50.380 32664-32664: unSubscribe
07-26 20:34:50.380 32664-32664: Super::onDestroy

Comment: according to the logs `onNext` and `onCompleted` are called. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @LordRaydenMK I think Frank is right! At that time it destroyed before  the observable completes! But this time! API has completed before the service has been destroyed. So does this happen at random then!? Then how should i handle now?

Comment: I suggest you to try RxFirebase library to make easier work with RxJava and Firebase together: https://github.com/FrangSierra/Rx2Firebase